# Why does scipy.optimize say it has succeeded when it fails?

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, numerical-methods

If I try to locate the (shallow) maximum of [Himmelblau's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himmelblau%27s_function) with a starting point even a little away from its true location, `scipy.minimize` (with its default BFGS algorithm) claims to have been successful, but has actually got lost up the steep sides of the function:

```
def f(X):
    x, y = X
    return (x**2 + y - 11)**2 + (x + y**2 - 7)**2

from scipy.optimize import minimize
minimize(lambda X: -f(X), (0.2, 0.2))
```

returns:

```
      fun: -1.317411760934999e+34
 hess_inv: array([[ 0.38662039, -0.49347889],
       [-0.49347889,  0.70730156]])
      jac: array([0., 0.])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 64
      nit: 2
     njev: 16
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([ 2.32731520e+08, -3.18111266e+08])
```

Why has it not been able to detect the failure here? The gradient is surely not zero at this point.

Comment: Provide analytic gradients instead of letting the solver do finite differences.

Comment: Thnaks. Can you expand a bit on why the finite difference calculation is failing without the algorithm noticing?

Comment: If the numerical gradient is computed with step size `h=1e-8` (absolute, not relative), then at the given point it will not change the floating point number, thus return the same function value in `f(x)` and `f(x+h*ek)` and thus give zero gradients.

Comment: Yes, in this case you loose all precision, but even more in general: solvers expect precise first derivatives and that means that if possible you should provide exact gradients.